# Unable to compile TinyOs applications with avr-gcc 4.2.1 but able to compile with avr-gcc 3.3

Tags: gcc, avr, avr-gcc, binutils, tinyos

i'm trying to compile TinyOs 1.x applications on my cygwin machine. I'm able to compile the applications of TinyOs 1.x using avr-gcc v3.3 but not with v4.2.1.

I wanted to upgrade my avr-gcc from v3.3 to v4.2.1 as there are support for new controllers. So i followed the steps that were provided to build the toolchains.

https://www.microchip.com/webdoc/AVRLibcReferenceManual/install_tools_1install_avr_binutils.html

I have used : *binutils-2.17, gcc-4.2-20070719 , avr-libc-1.8.1* to build my toolchain. I choose this versions because it is the base version for the new mcu's support.

Now when i try to compile the TinyOs applications using v4.2.1 , i'm stuck at the errors like this.
[Error Given while compiling with avr-gcc v4.2.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UMQt.png)

[Working with avr-gcc v3.3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRHxy.png)

And For v3.3 : *binutils-2.13, gcc-3.3 , avr-libc-20030512*.

and additionally : *nesc-1.1-1w.cygwin.i386.rpm, tinyos-1.1.0-1.cygwin.noarch.rpm, tinyos-tools-1.1.0-1.cygwin.i386.rpm, galsc-0.1.0-1.cygwin.i386.rpm* were installed for both the versions of avr-gcc.

**How can i fix this error ? If more information needed, feel free to ask. Thank you in advance .**

Comment: The actual job is develop a avr-gcc which has support for new mcus. The current version that is working is avr-gcc v3.3 which doesn't have support for new mcu's. So i had to look for the gcc which has an support for the new mcu's then make it compatible with TinyOS. Though the compilation i'm doing is for atmega128 which is supported by v3.3 and v4.2.1.

Comment: Please, add a fragment of `Clock.h` with lines which generate the error. `$` can't be used in C code but can in asm.

Comment: The error shown in lines of Clock.h has a enum declared, and its perfectly fine And there any many more errors like this in many other files.

Comment: @BiswajeetSahoo Please show us the error lines nevertheless. Please also compile with `-save-temps` and include the corresponding lines from the `.i` file if they are different in your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the new controllers to the the current gcc toochain.

I added the architectures to the my current toolchain. I have answered it here.

[Adding a architecture to the base toolchain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55234417/how-can-i-add-a-architecture-which-is-available-in-new-version-of-gcc-to-a-old-v/55573738#55573738)

Comment: Please elaborate how this answers the question.